# Vertices are not showing

Tags: vertices

I am following a tutorial where I've created a single vert object and am now trying to a subset of the vertices. However, I only two vertices are selectable as shown below the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuDT9N3ka0A&ab_channel=KeelanJon)'s example. Perhaps, I have accidentally hidden the vertices in the 3d Edit mode, but I couldn't find where to toggle that feature. Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image: tutorial mesh example w/ vertices selectable]

[image: my mesh with only two vert selectable]

[image: Mesh in object mode]
[image: morphed body in edit mode]

Comment: If only the two verts made from the single vert object you spawned are selectable, its because edit mode can only change one object at a time, or multiple if multiple are selected in object mode. To fix this, in object mode you can select the single vert object you made and the other mesh and join them with Cmd+J or Windows+J

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Blender. I switched back to Obj mode and tried to select what I thought was the Mesh and single vertex only to receive a "No mesh to join" error at the bottom. Is the mesh the whole body itself? Sorry again, for I am not familiar with the terminology.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do. Could please try sharing either the youtube tutorial you are following and its relevant timestamp or a blend file with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I just linked the tutorial in the description above. Go to 2:13 in the video. Right after he creates the single vertex, you can see all the black dots on each vertex of the mesh unlike mine.

Comment: Do they show up normally in edit mode when you press 1 after selecting it?

Comment: Nope, only 8 points on one side that's mirrored when you extrude on them. I'll add a picture of that above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119801/discussion-between-user109540-and-nascent-space).

Comment: Watch this video. I spent 3 hours trying to figure out the same. When you add a modifier it has to also be applied afterwards for it to work. After adding the modifiers, enter object mode. Go to each modifier and use the dropdown arrow next to the camera icon and select "apply" then when you go back into edit mode you should see the vert points: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUbg-V_vRM0&ab_channel=TheCGEssentials

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any modifiers active? If so try applying them to see if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the skin modifier on vertices that you keep on extruding, the vertices are *inside* of the mesh, not *on* the mesh surface. You'll need to enable xray.

If you've hidden any vertices, in edit mode, try <kbd>a</kbd> to select all vertices, then <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> to unhide any hidden vertices.

[image: xray]